# why my class can not be found?

Tags: php, class, exception

Doing some php and the root directory looks like this:

```
web/
    -index.php
src/
    -Controllers/
        -IndexController.php
    -Services/
        -IpService.php
```

class IpService has namespace Service
i added this namespace to autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Service\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

and in the IndexController.php im doing this:

```
use Services\IpService;

$app['ip_service'] = function () {
    return new IpService();
};
```

but when i call  `$app['ip_service']->get()` i'm getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Services\IpService' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\src\Controllers\IndexController.php on line 18
```

Comment: Can you share the code that autoloads? Initially it sounds like a path issue.

Comment: updated my question im using composer

Comment: Your autoload field for composer references a namespace named "Service" but your folder structure and IndexController.php reference "Services".

Comment: good it did a job thanks

Comment: I'll post that as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autoload field for composer references a namespace named "Service" but your folder structure and IndexController.php reference "Services".